# Can I use Spring Data JPA with PostgreSQL?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, postgresql-9.5

I would like to be able to use a PostgreSQL database using Spring Data JPA. Can I do this?

To clarify, I'd like to be able to use things just as the `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`, just instead of hooking to an H2 in-memory database, it hooks into a PostgreSQL database.

I am following this tutorial, which uses an H2 database: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse.

You've to perform multiple steps

1. Add postgresql dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Configure database details in `application.properties` or `application.yml` like below;

   ```
   spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>
   spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
   spring.datasource.username=<USERNAME>
   spring.datasource.password=<PASSWORD>
   spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect #Or any other dialect if you're using updated.
   ```
3. Replace <> with your postgres details

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thank you!